# Errors including and calling FBXLoader with Three.js

Tags: javascript, plugins, three.js, fbx

I'm new to three.js and I was following along a [tutorial](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2019/10/14/how-to-create-an-interactive-3d-character-with-three-js/) on loading GLTF Models using Three.js. I wanted to practice by using the FBX loader to import and animate models from Mixamo.

The tutorial used CDNs for the three.min.js and GLTFLoader files. I tried doing the same for the FBXLoader. However, I keep getting errors calling the FBXLoader from my main.js file

In my HTML I have:

In my main.js I've tried calling it like so:

```
const loader = new THREE.FBXLoader();
```

and

```
const loader = new FBXLoader();
```

then get the following respective errors

```
Uncaught TypeError: THREE.FBXLoader is not a constructor

Uncaught ReferenceError: FBXLoader is not defined
```

I've messed around with it quite a bit, and tried removing the type "module" and changing "jsm" to "js" with no luck either. (Plus I also encounter a deprecation warning when I do that). I don't have the best understanding of importing plugins from three.js so any clarification would help.

Also, I see that GLTF is the preferred format for Three.js, should I convert my FBX model and animations from Mixamo to GLTF using blender?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Did you try loading the FBXLoader first via script- tag in your html as it must be before instantiating it ? If not, load the .js- version.